# Python split complex windows command string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking for a way to split a complex windows command string like:

```
"C:\\DOCUME~1\\<USER>~1\\LOCALS~1\\Temp\\is-M186E.tmp\\one.exe C:\\two.exe\" Track=\"0011011000\"\""
```

(one process starting another process with options) in order to obtain the first executable file name, e.g. `one.exe`.

Since those strings come from various logs, they can be very complex and I don't know if there will be white spaces in the directory names.
Does anyone have a clue on how to do this?

I am using python 3 on a linux machine.

Edit: OK sorry, I was misleading, I don't know a priori the file extension. It may not be an `.exe`

Comment: are you just looking for an .exe file?

Comment: @CIsForCookies nope, unfortunately I don't know the file extension a priori

Comment: So what do you know?  There is a list of extensions you are looking for?

Comment: @CIsForCookies not much actually, only that it is on windows. I don't know if it can help, but the strings are the created processes extracted from VirusTotal Behavior API.

Comment: You must know what you are looking for or else there is nothing you can do... check the strings, and figure out what is the substring that is right for you

Comment: @CIsForCookies I was fearing that. I just hoped that someone could come up with some real deep regex magic. :)

Answer (score 0):

First, split the string to substrings with split ('\') and go over the resulting tuple in a loop, seaching for the `.exe` like this

```
for sub in str.split ('\\'):
    if '.exe' in sub:
        return sub
```

If you have number of optional extensions, change the condition to look for list of strings, i.e. (`if sub[-3:] in [str1, str2]`)

Answer (score 0):

```
import re  

st = r"C:\\DOCUME~1\\<USER>~1\\LOCALS~1\\Temp\\is-M186E.tmp\\one.exe C:\\two.exe  C:\\three.wav\" Track=\"0011011000\"\""
```

> for different extentions add |\w+.ext to the pattern

```
pattern = r'\\(\w+\.exe|\w+\.wav)'

print(re.findall(pattern,st))

['one.exe', 'two.exe', 'three.wav']
```